# Custom API data fetching hook keeps rerendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I've created a custom hook which I want to use to fetch data with. Now I've come a long way with some help from several blog articles, but there's just one thing I want to improve on. I have a custom hook which fetches data using a useEffect hook. This way the data is fetched upon render, and when for example query params change. Now the useEffect has a caveat. When I include a dependency array with anything in it, it's all fine, but I get a warning that the hook is dependent on a value. I don't like warnings so I add the value to the dependency array, but for some reason then it just keeps rerendering. Below is my useApi hook:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { AxiosError, AxiosRequestConfig, AxiosResponse } from "axios";
import api from "./config/api-config";

const useApi = (axiosParams: AxiosRequestConfig) => {
  const [response, setResponse] = useState<AxiosResponse>();
  const [error, setError] = useState<AxiosError>();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(axiosParams.method === "GET");

  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      const result = await api.request(axiosParams);
      setResponse(result);
    } catch (err: any) {
      setError(err);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Render useApi");
    axiosParams.method === "GET" && fetchData();
  }, [axiosParams.method, fetchData]);

  return { response, error, loading, fetchData };
};

export default useApi;
```

And this is where I'm using it:

```
import { FC, useState } from "react";
import { Wrapper } from "./home.style";
import { HomeProps } from "./home.types";
import useApi from "../../../api/useApi";

const Home: FC<HomeProps> = () => {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState<String>();

  const { response, loading, error, fetchData } = useApi({
    method: "GET",
    url: "/books/v1/volumes",
    params: {
      q: "",
    },
  });

  return <Wrapper></Wrapper>;
};

export default Home;
```

I've tried using a callback hook for the fetchData function, but then the issue with the dependency array moves from the useEffect to the useCallback. Does anyone know how I should handle this?

Comment: Take a look at your Home FC and useApi hook usage. The object you passing there is recreated on each render. You need to save the passing data with useMemo first (or useState). Additionally: conver your `fetchData` with useCallback. It is also reacreated on each render so it triggers your useEffect

Comment: Amazing! Yes, that's the one thing I didn't think of. Thanks for the help @SergeySosunov. It's fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

To answer as an answer:
Infinite reexecution of `useApi` hook is happening due to the object passed as a parameter is recreated on each component rerendering.

```
  const { ... } = useApi({
    method: "GET",
    url: "/books/v1/volumes",
    params: {
      q: "",
    },
  });
```

It will work fine in case a parameter is a plain string or a number. But in case of normal object or array, for example, you need to preserve a reference to them. You can either move this config out of functional component scope, i.e. just place it above it (if it is not meant to be modified), either preserve it with useMemo or useState hook.

```
// const useApiConfig = useMemo<AxiosRequestConfig>(() => {
const useApiConfig = useMemo(() => {
return {
  method: "GET",
  url: "/books/v1/volumes",
  params: { q: "" }
  };
}, [])

/* ... */

const { response, loading, error, fetchData } = useApi(useApiConfig);
```

Additionaly, due to `fetchData` is in `depsArray` of `useEffect` hook - it is important to wrap `fetchData` into `useCallback` due to without it `fetchData` will be recreated on each rerender and useEffect will be triggered. And due to reexport of the `fetchData` from the hook - component that is using it will also have an issues with rerender.

Usually (when reexport is not needed) method like `fetchData` is just placed inside of the useEffech hook itself (as a const function).

```
const useApi = (axiosParams: AxiosRequestConfig) => {
  const [response, setResponse] = useState<AxiosResponse>();
  const [error, setError] = useState<AxiosError>();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(axiosParams.method === "GET");

  const fetchData = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
      const result = await api.request(axiosParams);
      setResponse(result);
    } catch (err) {
      setError(err);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  }, [axiosParams]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Render useApi");
    axiosParams.method === "GET" && fetchData();
  }, [axiosParams.method, fetchData]);

  return { response, error, loading, fetchData };
};
```